# If $\sum a_n$ (positive terms) is convergent, then $a_n \leq M/n$ for some $M$, for all $n$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $(a_n)$ be a nonnegative real sequence. Assume that the series
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n
\end{equation}

is convergent. Is it true or false that there exists $M \geq 0$ such that
\begin{equation}
a_n \leq \frac{M}{n}
\end{equation}
for all $n$?

I don't have many clues!

Comment: What if $a_{2^n}=1/2^{n/2}$, $a_n=0$ otherwise?

Comment: This statement is true if $a_n$ is monotonically decreasing